# The proper phrase for video destination

Tags: word-request

What would you say call devices which could be picked to display some video in one generalized word?

The context is

> In this application you can switch video sources and destination screens.

There are a few *video sources*: a laptop and a camera. And several *"destinations"* that could display an image from those sources - they are projector, display 1 and 2.

What could I call them in one word? Or probably *destination screens* is understandable?

Comment: A projector isn't a "screen" strictly speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this application you can switch the video source and send the video output to any one of  three display devices.

Comment: Could we say it shorter to *In this application you can switch the video source and  output*?

Comment: *switch* could be confusing. **choose** would be better.